# using SSIS to copy a file

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql, ssis

When trying to run a task to copy a file, I'm getting this message:

```
TITLE: Package Validation Error
------------------------------

Package Validation Error

------------------------------
ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:

Error at File System Task: Failed to lock variable "C:\Users\agordon\amtu2\DocumentTransport\production\reports\ORDER18940610353.txt" for read access with error 0xC0010001 "The variable cannot be found. This occurs when an attempt is made to retrieve a variable from the Variables collection on a container during execution of the package, and the variable is not there. The variable name may have changed or the variable is not being created.".

Error at File System Task [File System Task]: An error occurred with the following error message: "Failed to lock variable "C:\Users\agordon\amtu2\DocumentTransport\production\reports\ORDER18940610353.txt" for read access with error 0xC0010001 "The variable cannot be found. This occurs when an attempt is made to retrieve a variable from the Variables collection on a container during execution of the package, and the variable is not there. The variable name may have changed or the variable is not being created.".
".

Error at File System Task: There were errors during task validation.

 (Microsoft.DataTransformationServices.VsIntegration)

------------------------------
BUTTONS:

OK
------------------------------
```

My schema looks like this:

[image]

Here are the properties of the failing component:

[image]

Here is the expressions section of the failing componenet:

[image]

And finally, here are my parameters:

[image]

**What am I doing wrong?**

Should I completely eliminate this **File System Task** and replace it with a C# Script Task to copy the file?

Is there something obviously wrong with my process?

**I apologize for the size of the images, I think stackoverflow resizes them. The originals are here:**

http://screencast.com/t/PvjBHWWHQ8 
http://screencast.com/t/JWfs2n2uD8mu 
http://screencast.com/t/T68ttqHo 
http://screencast.com/t/89KCF8B0qBd

Answer (score 2):

the properties page is asking for a variable name and you are providing a file path.  Do you have a variable in your SSIS package that can hold the fully qualified file name?

Comment: In BIDS, when clicking on the design surface, then selecting menu item 'SSIS'->'Variables' do you have a global variable defined to hold this fully qualified file path, or perhaps you are using a looping structure where you want to interact with all files in a directory, where the file name would be placed in a variable?  If you want to use the same hard coded file name, set IsSourcePathVariable to false...

Comment: Looking again, it seems you are expecting the parameter variable @[$Package::OrderReportFileName] to hold the file path.  Can you just use that (as seen in URL http://screencast.com/t/JWfs2n2uD8mu)

Comment: By the way, is the source and destination the same fully qualified file name?  You are doing a copy, right?

Answer (score 1):

Your SourceVariable property (in screenshot #2) should refer to your a variable name, not the actual value of the variable.